# MVC 4 view model validation attribute - string length - error

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-5, attributes, string-length

I have this property on the MVC5 viewmodel with the StringLength validation attribute:

```
        [Required]
        [StringLength(4, MinimumLength = 4, ErrorMessage = "The postcodes must be 4 characters long.")]
        [Display(Name = "Postcode (four digits)")]
        public int Postcode { get; set; }
```

The client-side validation works, but when I execute the action by submitting the form I am getting this error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.
```

I know it is the attribute that's causing this because everything works when I comment out the [StringLength] attribute.

I suspect that this is to do with the fact that the property type is int. But how to specify string length validation of an integer property? Is putting string type in ViewModel and then parsing it to int in the controller the best solution or is there an attribute for that? At attribute-driven solution would be nice.

EDIT: I tried  [DataType(DataType.PostalCode)] but it didn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this for a postal code (zip code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataType attributes can't be used to validate user input. They only provide hints for rendering values using templated helpers.

The range is a perfect validation for int's.

```
[Required]
[Range(1000,9999, ErrorMessage="The postcodes must be 4 characters long.")]  
[Display(Name = "Postcode (four digits)")]
public int Postcode { get; set; }
```

Comment: I'm a little late to the party, but this was a great answer

Answer (score 2):

int uses range, strings use string length, you cannot convert string length to int. `[DataType(DataType.PostalCode)]` will only work with a string. for postal code you can do a few things.

I suggest to make it a string.

i would make it a string with RegularExpression:

```
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Postal Code is Required")]
        [DataType(DataType.PostalCode)]
        [RegularExpression(@"^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$", ErrorMessage = "Postal Code Invalid.")]
        [Display(Name = "Postcode (four digits)")]
        public string Postcode { get; set; }
```

Comment: Good solution +1 but too generic for my project, which is localised. Thanks for reminder about RE-based validation.